# Text being different sizes in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sure someone's had this problem before but I can't figure it out because I guess I just don't know enough.

I have a form. One of the inputs has some JS attached so that as the user types (keyup), a `div` elsewhere on the page updates with what they're typing. e.g. They type "hello" and it appears in a `div` below.

I don't want the `div` which updates to get any bigger than 900px wide and only one text line high.

At the minute I have the `div` with overflow hidden so any extra text just disappears, also I have the `maxlength` of the `input` set so it can't get too big. However, since different browsers  space text differently, in some browsers it'll allow (for example) 10 words, in others it'll allow 11.

I have done the css reset thing which is meant to get all browsers acting the same but the spacing of text doesn't seem too affected.

Is my only option trying to use css to make the spacing between characters the same accross browsers?

Can anyone suggest any alternatives?

**EDIT**

here's the css reset I'm using:

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,button,textarea,select,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}address,button,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,input,optgroup,option,select,strong,textarea,th,var{font:inherit}del,ins{text-decoration:none}li{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:baseline}sub{vertical-align:baseline}
```

The font I'm using is Arial 32px

Comment: What css reset page are you using?

Comment: text always looks different in different browsers... Are you using pixels for the `font-size`?

Comment: fyi on an entirely unrelated point: http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Comment: @Whetstone - I added the css reset

Comment: I'm such a tube I got the font wrong. It's Arial. @jackjoe I'm using px

Comment: @Joseph Interesting article actually. And not a totally unrelated point. A fairly related point I'd say. Well written article by the way. You're a good explainer :)

Comment: @crazysarah Whoa! wait... sorry.... very sorry... it's just an article I was linked to and it's written by someone way smarter than me. :P  That was written by [Andy E](http://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e)

Comment: @Joseph - hehe oh, sorry. Shame I was goina ask you how come your JS is so much different to mine (newbie) and how to change my crap keyup to the more sensible onkeydown suggestion outlined in that article. But you're not the right person and I've no idea whether you're an explainer or not. In case you are here's my (admittedly not working) jsfiddle of what I have http://jsfiddle.net/barricades/ZRv3y/2/

Comment: @crazysarah This is the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Qmh8m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS reset is a pretty poor one.  It fixes a lot of display problems but down not address text sizing at all, so it's useless for this issue.  You can find a more comprehensive one [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), but changing your reset page may have unintended effects.  I'll suggest using some inspection tools to check if you have padding or margin shrinking the available size to write text in, and if not then setting all aspects of the text so that it is rendered consistently.

Comment: Hey, thanks that worked perfectly. things look right now. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem!  Do you mind elaborating on what part worked for future Googlers?

Comment: Yeah, I just swapped the css reset I had (in the original Qu) with the css at the link you were kind enough to suggest and wham! :) I'm not sure exactly what the difference was because there's some commands in there I don't recognise. Is it something to do with the reset for older browsers in the new css?

Comment: The point of a css reset is to reset all of the properties that individual browsers set by default.  The reset page you had was great, but it did not reset the text formatting.